# heroku push factory_girl_rails bundle install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, bundle, factory-bot

I am trying to push my app to heroku. I type git push heroku and it returns with this:

```
git push heroku
Counting objects: 55, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Writing objects: 100% (36/36), 10.30 KiB, done.
Total 36 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
   You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
   You have deleted from the Gemfile:
   * factory_girl_rails (= 4.2.1)
   Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

   You have deleted from the Gemfile:
   * factory_girl_rails (= 4.2.1)
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:appname.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:appname.git'
```

I have added and removed factory_girl_rails to the gemfile multiple times and ran bundle install along with it.

I have tried doing the directions it gives, but I am unable to get it to work.

I am not sure what the problem is but it won't push to heroku.

Can anyone help?

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'devise'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

This is what it looks like with factory_girl_rails in my Gemfile.

Comment: I commented out  config.force_ssl = true

in the config/environments/production.rb file and it seemed to work. Anyone know why that works?

Comment: Is factory_girl inside a development/testing group in your Gemfile? You should add the contents of your Gemfile to the question.

Comment: Did you do what the error asked?  `bundle install` locally?  This should update your Gemfile.lock.  Commit the new one to Git and git push should fix it.  If not, the other option you could try is `git push heroku -f` to force update.

Comment: Yeah I ran multiple bundle installs and nothing seemed to help it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by commenting out

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

This was in the config/environments/production.rb file.

Any idea why this caused an error?